# Fire off opportunity process based on account object criteria?

Tags: process-builder, email-alert

Since Salesforce limits which objects can be referenced within an email alert, I'm needing to initiate an opportunity through criteria based on the account object.

**Use Case**:  Whenever a foundational partner is assigned (within the account object), send email alert to that foundational partner group that references the opportunity.

**Fields in question:**

- **Account:**  `foundational_partner__c`  (picklist type)
- **Opportunity:** `CIA_Partner_Type__c` (formula to the account `foundational_partner__c` field)

I've tried to initiate the process via the formula field, then realized I was unable to do that.  I then tried to initiate it via the "partner_type__c" on the account object, still didn't work.

I tried:

```
ISCHANGED([Opportunity].Account.Partner_Type__c
&&
ISPICKVAL([Opportunity].Account.Partner_Type__c, 'Test')
```

and also tried without the `ischanged` part, but no go.

I know I could solve this by creating the process within the account object, but then I wouldn't be able to reference the opportunity on the email alert.  Any way to solve this dilemma?

Comment: To be clear: you expect to be able to send an email for an opportunity when the account picklist changes?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make a single Process for this, because Processes can't directly detect changes to upstream (parent) records. Instead, you would need two Processes. The first would be on the account when the picklist changes, and would update the child opportunities for those records with a field specifically designed to act as a trigger for an Opportunity Process. From there, the Opportunity Process would send the emails and probably reset the field that triggered the email so that the process can be fired again in the future.